# MongoDB NumberDecimal: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal128' and 'Decimal128'

Tags: python, mongodb, decimal

I'm playing around with the new mongodb data type `NumberDecimal`. I generally build scientific apps requiring exact precision (or as exact as possible) so I'm wondering how I can use it.

One of the apps I'm building is a python flask app which pulls data from a database and performs a variety of calculations. However, when I pull a `NumberDecimal` from mongodb (let's say `NumberDecimal('24.55')`) and try to add it to a add it to a `bson.decimal128.Decimal128` number I created in python I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal128' and 'Decimal128'
```

And if I try to convert `NumberDecimal` to `decimal.Decimal` (or anything else):

```
TypeError: Cannot convert Decimal128('24.55') to Decimal
```

So I guess I have a few questions: (1) is there anyway to convert this `NumberDecimal` to anything I can use in python, (2) if not, is there a datatype I can convert all of my other numbers to that's compatible with `NumberDecimal`, (3) if not, seems to me the only way I can use it would be server-side using the aggregation framework (are there other use cases)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you need to cast Decimal128 instances to standard Python decimals in order to operate them. But you should do that inside a context created by `create_decimal128_context`, from `bson.decimal128`, to ensure results can later be stored in the database.

```
>>> from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128, create_decimal128_context
>>> import decimal
>>>
>>> D128_CTX = create_decimal128_context()
>>>
>>> with decimal.localcontext(D128_CTX):
...     d1 = Decimal128('1.23')
...     d2 = Decimal128('3.21')
...     d3 = Decimal128(d1.to_decimal() + d2.to_decimal())
...
>>> print(d3, type(d3))
4.44 <class 'bson.decimal128.Decimal128'>
>>> print(d3.to_decimal(), type(d3.to_decimal()))
4.44 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
>>> decimal.Decimal(d3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: conversion from Decimal128 to Decimal is not supported
```

And, as you can see by the last two commands above, to cast to Python's Decimal type, use the [Decimal128.to_decimal](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/decimal128.html#bson.decimal128.Decimal128.to_decimal) method. Do not attempt to pass a Decimal128 instance in the Decimal constructor.

Tested on Python 3.6 and pymongo 3.4.

Inspired on pymongo's [documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/decimal128.html) of the `bson.decimal128` module.

Comment: Awesome thanks my man! I'm realizing the headache of using these "precision" wrappers isn't really worth the negligible gain in precision/exactness haha

Comment: Imagine an invoice with 10 distinct line items each worth $0.10.  Sum() the line items, and your invoice is wrong.  The total should not be $0.9999999 (infinitely repeating).  Want to determine if the number has a limited number of decimal places? `0.27 % 0.001` does not equal zero, it equals 0.<17 zeroes>12143… I wouldn't call "going from the **wrong** answers to the _right_ answers" a "_negligible gain_".